# User interface compiler Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

i have created a UI with the Qt Designer, i want to integrate it into my cpp program now.

I have to convert the main_window.ui to a header file? 
Supposedly it should be a possibility via the Designer Form->View Code to give a cpp code to this class which I can copy directly into a header file? 
Unfortunately I get the error message : Unable to launch C:/Program Files(x86)/Qt Designer/bin/uic. 
Under my path exesterit no folder structure /bin ? 
I can't find a download for the user interface compiler either ?

Is there a simple solution? Or where is my mistake?

Comment: It seems like something with your installation is wrong. uic is the Qt tool that compiles your .ui files when you build your application. If it's not where it should be you obviously won't be able to do anything with you .ui file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time you don't need to call uic manually: just add the .ui files to your .pro files as "FORMS", and qmake will take care of the rest. See for example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#forms and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html